# How can I change a Meteor.users _id?

Tags: javascript, mongodb, meteor

I have some existing users from a non-Meteor app. I'd like to import them and keep their _id because I reference it in other documents.

I am able to create a user like this:

```
if (Meteor.users.find().count() === 0) {
    Accounts.createUser({
      username: 'test',
      email: 'test@example.com',
      password: 'password'
    });
  }
```

However, it doesn't seem to work to set the _id field in that block of code.

Is there a way to change the user's _id?

Comment: Is there a reason to not just import them via MongoDB tools rather than meteor? https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.collection.insert/#id-field

Comment: Well, I'm importing them through the airtable api.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using `Meteor.users.insert` instead of `Accounts.createUser`.  It's slightly more complicated and requires an extra step to set the password:

```
var newUserId = Meteor.users.insert({
      _id: 'whatever',
      profile  : { fullname : 'test' },
      email: ['test@example.com']
    })
Accounts.setPassword(newUserId, 'password');
```

Comment: Thanks. That let me set the _id. However, now I can't set the emails field unless it is in the profile. Do you know how I can get it to let me set the emails field without putting it in the profile? This is how it looks when I create a new user with the Accounts.ui package. ```{
  "_id": "uEfww8nKXqEFosKgA",
  "username": "webmagnets",
  "emails": [
    {
      "address": "foo@gmail.com",
      "verified": false
    }
  ]
}```

Comment: Never mind. I figured it out. Mongol shows me my own account's 'emails' when I'm logged in, but won't show my other accounts. This is good.